# Why can I access a local webserver on iphone, but not my Android phone?

Tags: wi-fi, web-server

I have an ESP32 Cam connected to my local wifi. As I understand it, the ESP32 Cam connects to the wifi and runs a webserver which serves up video controls and a video stream.

I can access this on my Linux PC, and my daughter's iphone, simply by typing http://192.168.1.132 into the web browser, but my Samsung Android phone does not let me see the device.

Strangely, the very first time I tried to access the ESP32 on my Android phone, I saw the camera image appear briefly.  Subsequently I get ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE.

Any idea what is going on, and how I can fix it ?

Comment: May the IP implementation of the ESP32 is a bit buggy or incompatible with the IP stack of Android. Make sure you are using the latest version of the used ESP32 libraries.